# In Ms access how to prevent people from having access to my query and report

Tags: dropbox, microsoft-office-2007

I have created a simple ms access database 
in that I have datatable, a data entry form, some specific way of query and reports specific for the queries.

Now I have to give this file to others dept. people as well who will only enter data for me.
I do not want them to access my query and reports so that it will not be changed by them.

How can I hide those options so that other will be able see only data entry form and datatable only from thier computer.

Also I want use dropbox for sharing my database with others so that when they make entry it will get updated in my computer as well. Is it possible to do Both (preventing access to certain options and sharing with drop box).

Kindly let me know how it is done.

Comment: What you want isn't possible.  If they have to have access to enter data they have access to use the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate Access database that you share for data entry purposes. This is the only database that you share on Dropbox. You keep another database where you keep queries and reports. Then you **link** the table from the Dropbox database to your private database.